# Displaying arabic test in Qt for Symbian

Tags: qt, qt4, symbian, symbian3

I have problem displaying arabic characters in Qt for symbian and have been stuck here the whole day, hope someone could help me out here.
Simply put, i have an arabic word, say العالمين (dont know the meaning of the word) and I have to display it using QGraphicsTextItem. 
Please provide me a piece of code that does this. Here's what i have tried in vain.

`QString name("العالمينن");`

`QTextStream *p = new QTextStream(&name);`

`p->setCodec("ISO8859-6");`

`QGraphicsTextItem *text = new QGraphicsTextItem(p->readAll());`

`text->setPos(0,50);`

`scene->addItem(text);`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In this case the phone should have default support for this font. Otherwise it will be displayed as boxes or will not show at all. However it will work fine in Desktop if that font is installed in the system.

To check whether the phone supports the font goto Settings -> General -> Personalisation -> Language -> Phone Language.